# Redireccionar a otra página JSF problemas con el menú

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, menu

este es mi primer proyecto con JSF y estoy teniendo problemas para la redirección en el menú.

Este es mi menú:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me ocurre es que si estoy en el index si funcionada pero si estoy en una de las páginas que están en el listado me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

admin/admin se duplica y por tanto no encuentra la página.

¿Cómo podría hacer para solucionar este fallo?.

un saludo.

Comment: En vez de añadir fotos del codigo, escribelo a mano...

Comment: Pon un "/" al inicio de URL: url="/admin..."